# Build a Loop that Sums Values and Adds to a List in a Certain Position in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, insert, append

I’m working on creating a loop that calculates income distribution based on tax returns. Let me give a simple example. Please keep in mind that this will only be a subset of the data I need to produce, but I want to keep it simple for readers.
I have 10 income groups which have each been assigned a number, 0-9. We’ll call this “group.” Let’s say I have another variable that is a list with 10 positions called “dist_agi.” This variable will represent total adjusted gross income for each group. It begins with a default of 0. 
In my loop, I want to take the adjusted gross income that is in the corresponding position, add it to the adjusted gross income for that tax return, and then place it in the correct position in the list. At the end, I should have 10 positions that that include the summations of adjusted gross income for that group. The idea is to have the position number represented by the group. So if group = 0, that adjusted gross income should be assigned the first position in the list. So if I have 5 returns for group 0 with an AGI of 10, the final value in that position should be 50.

```
dist_agi= [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for tax_return in returns:
    myCalculator.calculate_taxes(tax_return) #This is my tax calculator. 
    sum_dist_agi = dist_agi[tax_return.group] + tax_return.adjusted_gross_income
    dist_agi.insert(tax_return.group, sum_dist_agi)
return dist_agi
```

Unfortunately, when I run this, it doesn’t just produce the one list, but instead a bunch of values. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can make this work?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is, but what heppens if you take out `[]` in your `insert` call?

Comment: @zondo I made some changes to the above statement. The basic problem is this: I should receive only one list. But instead, it appears to be creating a list for each return.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, `dict_agi` should have a length of 10 (one value per group). However, in your code, the `insert` call increases the length of the list by 1 every time, so the total length of `dict_agi` ends up being `10 + len(returns)`.

I think that you do not need the `insert` call at all:

```
dist_agi= [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for tax_return in returns:
    myCalculator.calculate_taxes(tax_return) #This is my tax calculator. 
    dist_agi[tax_return.group] += tax_return.adjusted_gross_income
```

This way, `dist_agi` represents total adjusted gross income for each group.

Comment: Yes the final length should be 10. I'll try what you suggested. Your intuition sounds right to me.

Comment: Looks I get at list index out of range error when I try your suggestion.

Comment: @AlexDurante Then the `tax_return.group` is not a number between 0 and 9. Could it be going from 1 to 10. If so, just use `dist_agi[tax_return.group - 1] += tax_return.adjusted_gross_income`

Comment: Actually looks like I got it to work. Thanks for the help. I was overthinking this haha